# Adding a gap in geom_segment in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-segment

I have some data with `id`, `time_to_event`, `event`, therapy `start` and therapy `stop` variables.
Here is a reproducible example:

```
data <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 7L, 
8L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c("1", "4", "2", "9", "5", "10", "7", "8", 
"3", "6"), class = "factor"), event = c("Death", "Death", "Death", 
"Y", "Death", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Death", "X"), time_to_event = c(89L, 
83L, 74L, 88L, 78L, 72L, 77L, 76L, 79L, 78L), start = c(18L, 
3L, 13L, 16L, 10L, 6L, 20L, 11L, 14L, 9L), stop = c(89L, 83L, 
74L, 88L, 78L, 72L, 77L, 76L, 79L, 78L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I computed a plot, which shows the type of `event` as `geom_point` and the time of the therapy as `geom_segment` with `start` and `stop`. Here is the code:

```
colors <- c("X" = "dodgerblue3", 
            "Y" = "red2",
            "Death" = "black") # Defining the colors for the event type

event_symbols <- c("X" = "\u25CF",
                   "Y" = "\u25CF", 
                   "Death" = "\u2020") # <-- Problem: When I use the shape 84 (T) the code is plotted. When I use "/u2020", I get the above-mentioned error message

five_day_lines <- seq(0, 90, 5)
day_lines <- 1:90
day_lines <- day_lines[!day_lines %in% five_day_lines]

data$id <- factor(data$id, levels = data$id[order(data$time_to_event, decreasing = T)])

ggplot(data = data) +
  
  geom_hline(yintercept = five_day_lines, color = "grey", alpha = .35) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = day_lines, color = "grey", alpha = .25) +
  
  geom_segment(aes(x = id, xend = id, y = start, yend = stop), color = "dimgray", size = 1) +
  
  geom_point(aes(x = id, y = time_to_event, shape = event, color = event), size = 3) +
  
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,90), breaks = c(seq(0, 90, 5)), name = "Days after study inclusion") + 
  scale_x_discrete(name = "ID") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_color_manual(values = colors, breaks = c()) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = event_symbols, breaks = c("X", "Y", "Death"),
                     guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = c("dodgerblue3", "red2", "black")))) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.title = element_text(size=12, face="bold"),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.background = element_blank()) +
  labs(color="Medication", shape="Event type")
```

The plot looks like the following:

[image: Example Plot]

My question is, whether it is possible to add a gap in the `geom_segment` at a certain point, let's say at half of the length of the segments. Ideally, the break should look like a 'typical' gap in a plot axis like the following from https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/235467_5abd31ab564a43c9ae0f18cdd07eebe7.html:

[image: Example]

Here, we can see a kind of double slash. I had the idea of taking the double slash unicode character ([Link](https://unicode-table.com/en/20EB/)) but this, I think, would simply generate a new layer and would disregard the desired gap or 'interruption' of the `geom_segment`. Is there a smart way to compute such a gap, where the `geom_segment` ends at the one slash and starts again at the 2nd slash? Ideally, it works with the double slash but if there is another way with another appropriate shape or something else, I would be fine with that.

I would be grateful, if there is a smart solution for this problem.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, do you want an axis break or simply a gap in your segments?

Comment: Sorry for that, I thought it is understandable. I want a gap in the segments NOT in the axis. The second plot was just for showing the desired format/design of the gaps.

Comment: And ideally the gap in the segments should look like the axis breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there exists specialised layers in ggplot2 or extensions that deal with gaps specifically. One can of course abuse the `arrow` argument in `geom_segment()` to draw a stumpy arrow at the extremes of a segment, but that probably doesn't alleviate the necessity to use a second layer. Below you'll find a simplified example of that.

```r
library(ggplot2)

data <- structure(list(
  id = structure(c(1L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 6L), 
                 .Label = c("1", "4", "2", "9", "5", "10", "7", "8", "3", "6"), 
                 class = "factor"), 
  event = c("Death", "Death", "Death", "Y", "Death", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Death", "X"), 
  time_to_event = c(89L, 83L, 74L, 88L, 78L, 72L, 77L, 76L, 79L, 78L), 
  start = c(18L, 3L, 13L, 16L, 10L, 6L, 20L, 11L, 14L, 9L), 
  stop = c(89L, 83L, 74L, 88L, 78L, 72L, 77L, 76L, 79L, 78L)), 
  row.names = c(NA, -10L), 
  class = "data.frame"
)

gap_start <- 30
gap_stop <- 50

ggplot(data, aes(x = start, xend = stop, y = id, yend = id)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = gap_start), arrow = arrow(90, unit(1, "mm"))) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = gap_stop), arrow = arrow(90, unit(1, "mm"), ends = "first"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>